# hide parent div if its child div doesn't contain children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide the `category` div if `product` div doesn't contain child.

Here is my `HTML`.

```
<div class="fieldset categories">
  <h3>1) Category #3</h3>
  <div class="products">
    <div id="product_2509" class="product">
      <div class="show">
        <label> XYZ </label>
        <p> Price: <strong> $50 </strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="fieldset categories">
  <h3>2) Category #4</h3>
  <div class="products">
    <div id="product_2510" class="product">
      <div class="show">
        <label> XYZ </label>
        <p> Price: <strong> $50 </strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="product_2511" class="product">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="fieldset categories">
  <h3>3) Category #5</h3>
  <div class="products">
    <div id="product_2512" class="product">

    </div>
    <div id="product_2515" class="product">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="fieldset categories">
  <h3>4) Category #6</h3>
  <div class="products">
    <div id="product_2512" class="product">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If `.product` div doesn't contain any child then I need to hide the `fieldset categories` div.
But any of the `.product` of fieldset` categories" contains child then I need to show the parent div.
In above example:

Div I need to hide(all `.product` doesn't contain child)

1) Category #5

2) Category #6

Div I need to show(any of the `.product` contains child)

1) Category #3

2) Category #4 (because 1 child contains children)

Comment: will be happy to help if can see what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.categories').hide();
$(function(){
$(".product").each(function(){
    $(this).children('.show').parents('.categories').show();
});
});
```

or

```
$('.categories').hide();
$(function(){
$(".show").each(function(){
    $(this).parents('.categories').show();
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vodaaL1d/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$(".product").each(function(){
    if($(this).children().length==0)
    {
        $(this).parents(".categories").hide();
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Did you check Category #4, that should not hide because its first child has childrens.